# Column name in Csv changes after merging

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have multiple csv files that i need to merge. The column names are:

```
idSite  idVisit visitIp visitorId
```

However in the merged file the column `'idSite'` changes to  `'ï»¿idSite'`
This is the program i wrote. Everything else seems to be fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
dirListing = os.listdir("D:/Python/Test/Diku/piwik/filteredcsv/")

df=[]
siteIds = [34]
for id in siteIds: 
    for item in dirListing:
        if str(id) in item:
            print item        
            df.append(pd.read_csv(item,sep = ",",dtype='unicode')) 

    df3 = pd.concat(df,axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    df3.to_csv('merged_' + str(id) + '_raw'+'.csv', sep =',')
```

Can't seem to figure out the problem. Is it a encoding issue?

Comment: I believe that's the Byte Order Mark or BOM, probably the first character in the file. Try `encoding="utf-8-sig"` for `read_csv`

Comment: Also under the visitIp there are certain rows where the value is shown as `2.45849E+15` instead of `2458491605886220`. Any idea on why this happens

Comment: @user3220892, 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)